# popup excel file using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache poi I am reading a file and then updating the file from data base and storing in my local system inside `d` drive. For that I have written the below code and its working fine.

But now instead of storing in the local system I want to popup that file and show the result.

How to do that?

```
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\update5.xls"));
workbook.write(outFile);
           //file.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by pop up? do you want to download the file once it if generated to user browser?

Comment: popup that file and show the result ?? 
pop that file, meaning what you want to do ? open that file ? and what result you want to show ?

Comment: whats the problem , read the written file and show in some pop up window using some table or some mark up language

Comment: Hussain i have all ready read the file and i am writing to this file instead of that i want it to popup.can you please give some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're asking how to open the file for the user to see.

In case of desktop app:

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\fileToOpen.xls"));`

In case of web app:

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"fileToOpen.xls\"");`

Answer (score 0):

For linux .xls

```
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+
    + ExcelName + ".xls");
```